# how to sort before querying in the embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I know how to sort the embedded document after the find results but how do I sort before the find so that the query itself is run on the sorted array ? I know this must be possible if I use aggregate but i really like to know if this is possible without that so that I understand it better how it works.

This is my embedded document

```
   "shipping_charges" : [
            {
                    "region" : "region1",
                    "weight" : 500,
                    "rate" : 10
            },
            {
                    "region" : "Bangalore HQ",
                    "weight" : 200,
                    "rate" : 40
            },
            {
                    "region" : "region2",
                    "weight" : 1500,
                    "rate" : 110
            },
            {
                    "region" : "region3",
                    "weight" : 100,
                    "rate" : 50
            },
            {
                    "region" : "Bangalore HQ",
                    "weight" : 100,
                    "rate" : 150
            }
    ]
```

This is the query i use to match the 'region' and the 'weight' to get the pricing for that match ..

```
db.clients.find( { "shipping_charges.region" : "Bangalore HQ" ,  "shipping_charges.weight" : { $gte : 99 }  }, { "shipping_charges.$" : 1 }  ).pretty()
```

This query currently returns me the

```
     {
    "shipping_charges" : [
            {
                    "region" : "Bangalore HQ",
                    "weight" : 200,
                    "rate" : 40
            }
    ]
```

}

The reason it possibly returns this set is because of the order in which it appears(& matches) in the embedded document.

But, I want this to return me the last set that best matches to closest slab of the weight(100grams)

What changes required in my existing query so that I can sort the embedded document before the find runs on them to get the results as I want it ?

If for any reasons you are sure this cant be done without a MPR, let me know so that i can stay away from this method and focus only on MPR to get the desired results as I want it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregation pipeline instead of map-reduce:

```js
db.clients.aggregate([
    // Filter the docs to what we're looking for.
    {$match: {
        'shipping_charges.region': 'Bangalore HQ',
        'shipping_charges.weight': {$gte: 99}
    }},

    // Duplicate the docs, once per shipping_charges element
    {$unwind: '$shipping_charges'},

    // Filter again to get the candidate shipping_charges.
    {$match: {
        'shipping_charges.region': 'Bangalore HQ',
        'shipping_charges.weight': {$gte: 99}
    }},

    // Sort those by weight, ascending.
    {$sort: {'shipping_charges.weight': 1}},

    // Regroup and take the first shipping_charge which will be the one closest to 99
    // because of the sort.        
    {$group: {_id: '$_id', shipping_charges: {$first: '$shipping_charges'}}}
])
```

You could also use `find`, but you'd need to pre-sort the `shipping_charges` array by `weight` in the documents themselves.  You can do that by using a `$push` update with the [`$sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort) modifier:

```js
db.clients.update({}, {
    $push: {shipping_charges: {$each: [], $sort: {weight: 1}}}
}, {multi: true})
```

After doing that, your existing query will return the right element:

```js
db.clients.find({ 
    "shipping_charges.region" : "Bangalore HQ",
    "shipping_charges.weight" : { $gte : 99 }
}, { "shipping_charges.$" : 1 } )
```

You would, of course, need to consistently include the `$sort` modifier on any further updates to your docs' `shipping_charges` array to ensure it stays sorted.

Comment: Thanks, Johnny HK.  sorry, i meant the "aggregation" method instead of a MPR. So, you think its not possible without an aggregation thought my requirement is just to have an additional sort method for "weight" in ascending before the "find" actually runs on the array ?

Comment: @Param I've updated my answer to include a way to do it with `find`.

Comment: If we reorder the items of shipping_charges, the find() result will be different (I tested), but aggregation works nice +1

Comment: I think that would be nice if i can pre-sort before inserting them all to my collection so that it will stay sorted always since this collection would not be allowed to edit but can be deleted to make sure it will be in the way i inserted to the collection. but, when i tried to pre-sort them it says "slice" is expected. like the error "cannot have a $sort without a $slice"

Comment: @Param I'm guessing you're using MongoDB 2.4.x? In 2.6+ you can now use $sort without $slice.

Comment: Yes, I am using 2.4.9, fortunately my production is in 2.6.5. i will test it out without slice in my production and confirm back. thank you for pointing me.